# Why I can't see a security tab in the Workspaces section of GeoServer 2.17.2?

Tags: geoserver

I installed the last version of GeoServer. According to GeoServer documentation, I should be able to modify the security of the workspace with a dedicated tab on **Edit Workspace**, when I click on a workspace name. However, as you can see in the snapshot, my GeoServer is not showing the security tab. How can I enable this tab?

[image]

In GeoServer documentation, **Edit Workspace** clearly has a **security** tab

[Geoserver document link about workspaces](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/webadmin/workspaces.html)

Comment: How did you install GeoServer?

Comment: I did download from official geoserver web site,  http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.17.2/geoserver-2.17.2-bin.zip

Comment: Odd, I checked with 2.17.1 and Security tab is there, for the existing workspaces and for a new one that I created.

Comment: @user30184. I can't see the tab in my own GeoServer. It's a development installation, in which security concerns are secondary. Perhaps it has something to do.

Comment: I installed GeoFence extention, Is it possible geofence extension cause to security tab in edit workspace disabled or disappeared! ?

Comment: hmmm, may be, developer did that change from 2.17.2, but I don't know why they didn't mention in official document

Comment: see it in 2.17.2 for existing  and new workspaces

Comment: About GeoFence, it should be easy to test by removing temporarily and restarting.